# Using NZ in a function in VBA to build query

Tags: sql, oracle, vba, ms-access, inner-join

I am really struggling here. I am building up a query inside VBA to link to several tables inside Oracle and inside Access. I need to make sure what I have uploaded to Oracle Matches what is in the Access DB.

I have:

- SourceField1 (Always populated)
- SourceField2 (Sometimes populated)

If source field 2 is blank I want to ignore it and not join to it. The best way I have done this is try with an Nz and replace with SourceField1.

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO ERROR_TABLE (ORACLE_FIELD, TRANSFORM_FIELD) SELECT " & MatchValues!ORACLE_TABLE_NAME & "." & MatchValues!FieldName & ", " & MatchValues!TRANSFORM_TABLE_NAME & "." & MatchValues!FieldName
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM " & MatchValues!TRANSFORM_TABLE_NAME & " INNER JOIN " & MatchValues!xfTableName
strSQL = strSQL & " ON " & MatchValues!TRANSFORM_TABLE_NAME & "." & MatchValues!SourceField1 & " = " & MatchValues!xfTableName & "." & MatchValues!ReferenceField1 & ""
strSQL = strSQL & " AND " & MatchValues!TRANSFORM_TABLE_NAME & ".Nz(" & MatchValues!SourceField2 & "," & MatchValues!SourceField1 & ") = " & MatchValues!xfTableName & ".Nz(" & MatchValues!ReferenceField2 & "," & MatchValues!ReferenceField1 & ")"
strSQL = strSQL & " INNER JOIN " & MatchValues!ORACLE_TABLE_NAME & " ON (" & MatchValues!xfTableName
strSQL = strSQL & ".KEYVAL = " & MatchValues!ORACLE_TABLE_NAME & ".KEYVAL)"
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE (" & MatchValues!TRANSFORM_TABLE_NAME & "." & MatchValues!FieldName
strSQL = strSQL & " <> " & MatchValues!ORACLE_TABLE_NAME & "." & MatchValues!FieldName & ")"
```

Which gives me this:

> INSERT INTO ERROR_TABLE (ORACLE_FIELD, TRANSFORM_FIELD) SELECT UNI73MART1_DCappl.DECSN, tbluniDCappl.DECSN FROM tbluniDCappl INNER JOIN XF_DC_ref ON tbluniDCappl.REFVAL = XF_DC_ref.REFVAL AND tbluniDCappl.Nz(,REFVAL) = XF_DC_ref.Nz(,REFVAL) INNER JOIN UNI73MART1_DCappl ON (XF_DC_ref.KEYVAL = UNI73MART1_DCappl.KEYVAL) WHERE (tbluniDCappl.DECSN <> UNI73MART1_DCappl.DECSN)

Comment: Pretty sure NZ() is Access only and is not used like that anyway.  `NVL(a, b)` returns `b` if `a` is `null` else `a`.

Comment: I am running the select inside access (linked tables) so it would have to be an NZ function i think? What do you mean it isnt used like that anyway, is there an error in my query?

Comment: you have nothing to check "Nz(<<<MISSING>>>,REFVAL)" and you don't need the .  SQL error I think, `nz([tbluniDCappl],"Nothing")`

Comment: What about if I wrapped if statements around the strSQL, like if SourceField2 is not null then strSQL & ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this with proper concatenation of the Nz expressions:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO ERROR_TABLE (ORACLE_FIELD, TRANSFORM_FIELD) SELECT " & MatchValues!ORACLE_TABLE_NAME & "." & MatchValues!FieldName & ", " & MatchValues!TRANSFORM_TABLE_NAME & "." & MatchValues!FieldName
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM " & MatchValues!TRANSFORM_TABLE_NAME & " INNER JOIN " & MatchValues!xfTableName
strSQL = strSQL & " ON " & MatchValues!TRANSFORM_TABLE_NAME & "." & MatchValues!SourceField1 & " = " & MatchValues!xfTableName & "." & MatchValues!ReferenceField1 & ""
strSQL = strSQL & " AND " & MatchValues!TRANSFORM_TABLE_NAME & "." & Nz(MatchValues!SourceField2, MatchValues!SourceField1) & " = " & MatchValues!xfTableName & "." & Nz(MatchValues!ReferenceField2, MatchValues!ReferenceField1) & ")"
strSQL = strSQL & " INNER JOIN " & MatchValues!ORACLE_TABLE_NAME & " ON (" & MatchValues!xfTableName
strSQL = strSQL & ".KEYVAL = " & MatchValues!ORACLE_TABLE_NAME & ".KEYVAL)"
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE (" & MatchValues!TRANSFORM_TABLE_NAME & "." & MatchValues!FieldName
strSQL = strSQL & " <> " & MatchValues!ORACLE_TABLE_NAME & "." & MatchValues!FieldName & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Pull the call to Nz out of the SQL.  The two fields in question exist in the VBA context and so should be checked within the VBA code, not embedded in the SQL string.

```
strSQL = strSQL & " AND " & MatchValues!TRANSFORM_TABLE_NAME & "." Nz( MatchValues!SourceField2 , MatchValues!SourceField1) & " = " & MatchValues!xfTableName & "." & Nz( MatchValues!ReferenceField2 , MatchValues!ReferenceField1)
```

When NULL is concatenated with a string using `&`, null is just converted to a blank string.  So the expression `".Nz(" & MatchValues!SourceField2 & "," & MatchValues!SourceField1 & ") = " & MatchValues!xfTableName & ".Nz(" & MatchValues!ReferenceField2 & "," & MatchValues!ReferenceField1 & ")"` would simply produce the string value `".Nz(, SourceField1Name) = tablename.Nz(,ReferenceField1Name)`... which is bad SQL syntax.  I think Nathan_Sav was trying to point this out, but not very clear about it.

Hint 1: You should always debug an SQL statement built in code by printing out the actual SQL statement.  You should have included that in your question.

Hint 2: Try using the VBA line continuation character _